# Histogram equalization not working for color image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying histogram equalization but its giving me the same image as the input.

It seems like histogram equalization is having no impact. Can anyone tell where am I going wrong?

```
private static Mat adjustBrightnessContrast(Mat srcImage){
        Mat filterImage = srcImage.clone();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(srcImage,filterImage,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);
        java.util.List<Mat> filterImageList = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
        Core.split(filterImage,filterImageList);
        Mat luminance = filterImageList.get(0);
        Imgproc.equalizeHist(luminance,luminance);
        filterImageList.set(0,luminance);
        Core.merge(filterImageList,srcImage);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(filterImage,srcImage, Imgproc.COLOR_YCrCb2BGR);
        return srcImage;
    }
```

What I have done is converted the image from BGA to YCrCb format, and then performed histogram equalization on the first channel that is 0, after converting the image to `list` format.
Then the Mat format I got after implement hist. eq. I replace the `list` with it. And finally `merge` the list with the sourceImage.

But I am getting the same output as input.

I am trying on this image as:

[image]

PS : I think I am doing some mistake in color part of the conversion as GRAYSCALED images worked properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are merging `filterImageList` into `srcImage` but then using `filterImage`. Try replacing with this code, to merge into `filterImage`:

```
Core.merge(filterImageList,filterImage);
Imgproc.cvtColor(filterImage,srcImage, Imgproc.COLOR_YCrCb2BGR);
```